# UILabel doesn't clear, draws over previous contents

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UILabel whose text I change from time to time.  When I change the text, however, it doesn't erase the old text -- it re-draws on top of the old text and accumulates.

The UILabel is inside a UITableViewCell.

Has anyone encountered this problem?  How do you fix it?

Comment: You are probably re-creating the UILabel without realizing it. This would cause a new one to be placed over the existing one. Please give us some code so we can take a better look at it.

Comment: We need more code to determine what is going on.  A snippet or all of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would probably indicate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen when u customize `UITableViewCell` by `[cell addSubView:UILabel]` method.

So let me explain it in some detail:

We use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` method to get cell to use.

*This method can one of two thing:*

1. Return new object of UITableViewCell.
   OR
2. Return old object of UITableViewCell which is not right now on screen. (To improve performance)

If it is fresh than no problem but if it is not than the controls which we have added by 
`[view addSubView:view]` method are already there and we add it again on same position like 
 stack of same controls.

***We can solve it by two way:***

1. code in such a way that add [UIView addSubView:UIView] only if it is fresh cell.
2. (I suggest this) Use subclass of UITableViewCell also call Custom UITableViewCell.

*You will find many tutorial on this let me give u some:*

[Creating a Custom UITableViewCell](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/823_Creating_a_Custom_UITableViewCell.aspx)

[How To Design A Custom UITableViewCell From Scratch](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/)

If you are using storyboard than it is very easy:

[Creating Table Views with Storyboards](http://www.adoptioncurve.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Creating-Table-Views-With-Storyboards.pdf)

[Using Xcode Storyboards to Build Dynamic TableViews with Prototype Table View Cells](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells)

All the best...

Comment: When a cell is reused, is it cleared and then redrawn, or does it just draw on top of the old cell?

Comment: @Anna Dickinson : cell is not drawn on other cell. controls in cell drawn on old controls.

Comment: I have stuck in the same situation. I have created UILabel programatically and added the label on Scrollview. This label is used to display comments. Comments are greater than one so, I have created multiple labels according to comment count using for loop. Now when user adds new comment the label is recalled but new comment is overlapped with the previous comments. How to fix this issue. please Help! Thanks.

Comment: hi guys i am getting the same problem.  can we clear the uilabel previous value before we call this method again???

Answer (score 0):

people! I`ve come over similar problem and was trying to create new question, but I decided to write inside this topic for not to make new one. So here is the my case:

I am trying to develop localised app, in which English words set to label normally by `wordLabel.text = @"SomeNewWord";` but in case of Russian - new words are written above old ones. this case does not appear while I have some breakpoints to stop activity of the game. When there are no stopping factors the problem shows up. This happens only on iPhone with Russian language selected as default. on iPad everything goes well.  I also tried to `wordLabel.text` to `nil` before assigning new word to the ULLabel.  No reaction at all.  The problem is present on both simulator and iPhone 4s for now.
my UILabel is made from storyboard and has `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *wordLabel;`

UPDATE

after finding this post [useful one at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502482/uilabel-text-overlapping-on-update) I`ve solved my problem.  The answer was to UNCHECK Opaque in interface builder ...